# Embedding Mathematica in Confluence pages

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, confluence

What options are available in terms of embedding Wolfram Mathematica content (such as CDFs and Notebooks) into Atlassian Confluence pages? I'd like to use this for note-taking, so the ability to quickly edit the Mathematica content, via the Confluence page, would be optimal.

Comment: I don't know much about mathematica since I haven't used it since my Freshman year of college, but I doubt that confluence has the natural ability to allow editing of mathematica content. Confluence is just now getting around to permitting users to edit office documents within confluence pages. Also, a google search for confluence and mathematica returns no significant results

Comment: CDFs can be embedded in web pages, but they are not editable inside the browser.